# vim backbround color turns grey when set to white in vimrc

Tags: vim

when I give the command in normal mode

```
:highlight Normal ctermbg=white
```

the background turns white, but when I write the same in .vimrc, the background turns grey.
What is the problem here? I have tried setting background to light/dark, nothing works.
how can I fix this?

Comment: Where are you doing it in the `.vimrc`? Is there anything else there?

Comment: set t_Co=256 is also present, after the above setting. There's nothing else related to colors.

Comment: Can you comment out everything else in your `.vimrc` and try it?

Comment: `set t_Co=256` is generally useless, remove it from yor `vimrc`.

Comment: I had the same problem. The issue was with my iterm settings, not with vim. Check the color settings for  your terminal.

Comment: Problem solved, it was in fact a terminal setting problem. thanks.